# Django : An AppRegistryNotReady raised error when trying to connect a signal between different apps

Tags: python, django

I want to build an notification system in my django project. So I started to create an new app called notification. To create the notification I have to listen to the actions of the other models of my project. To reach this purpose I created in my notification app a signal handler :

in notification/signals.py

```
def create_subscription(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

I connect this handler to my signal in my notification/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from notification.signals import create_subscription
from django.conf import settings


class NotificationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'notification'

    def ready(self):
        post_save.connect(create_subscription, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, dispatch_uid="create_subscription")
```

This works fine. I used my custom User model defined in my settings.

But whenever I want to use another model of my project, like :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from notification.signals import create_subscription
from member.models import Participation


class NotificationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'notification'

    def ready(self):
        post_save.connect(create_subscription, sender=Participation, dispatch_uid="create_subscription")
```

I get an AppRegistryNotReady error, no matter which model I use.

I checked the order of declaration of my settings.INSTALLED_APPS, 'member' is declared before 'notification'.

When referring to the User model by passing threw the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL it's working fine, but when referring directly to the model it creates an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although you can’t import models at the module-level where AppConfig classes are defined, you can import them in ready(), using either an import statement or get_model().

You need to do like

```
class NotificationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'notification'

    def ready(self):
        from member.models import Participation

        post_save.connect(create_subscription, sender=Participation, dispatch_uid="create_subscription")
```

For more [info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. :-)